# Setting internal page links including anchors in sitecore 8

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore8

The new design for Inserting an Internal link( using General Link field type) in Sitecore 8 doesn't include Anchor attribute field but in an older version (i.e. sitecore 7), this field is available.
Is there a way by which authors can add anchor to an internal link in Sitecore 8?
Note: I need to add an internal link from one page to another page(with an anchor) and not an anchor within the same page.
I have attached screenshots from sitecore 7 and sitecore 8.

[Insert link pop up in sitecore 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rxDy.png)

[Insert link pop up in sitecore 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqZP.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is the blue **Anchor** button up in the left corner and also an **Insert anchor** button on the field itself:

[image: Link field]

Comment: Actually, the 'Anchor' button (up in the left corner of Sitecore 8 Insert link pop up) and the 'Insert Anchor' button inserts anchor to the same page url itself but I want to set an internal link to another page and then insert anchor to that link, for e.g. I have an Employee page and I want to add a link in that page that points to Manager page and an anchor to the Manager page, so that I can navigate to an anchor section in the Manager page from the Employee page. Has sitecore intentionally removed the anchor link or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Sitecore 8 SPEAK dialog. The temporary workaround is to revert to the previous dialog by commenting out (or better yet `<patch:delete />`) the following line in the **/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Speak.Applications.config**:

`<override dialogUrl="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx" with="/sitecore/client/applications/dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog" />`

The corresponding public reference number for this issue is #407189

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to customise the Speak dialog to add this back in here:
https://exlrtglobal.atlassian.net/wiki/display/~Drazen.Janjicek/2016/03/18/Extending+Sitecore+8.1+-+Adding+support+for+anchors+in+internal+links